# Why do named arguments work for np.reshape but not x.reshape?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to python but quite experienced in R, so I'm a bit puzzled by how functions, methods, and modules work.

In the following example, why does `x.reshape` not seem to allow named arguments whereas named arguments in `np.reshape` work fine?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(3,3,2)
x.reshape( (np.prod(x.shape),1)) #works fine
x.reshape(newshape = (np.prod(x.shape),1))  #TypeError: 'newshape' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
np.reshape(a = x, newshape = (np.prod(x.shape),1) ) #works fine
```

More generally, where can I read more about the distinctions between calling a function from a module on an object x versus calling the same method that is an attribute of that object?

```
print(type(x.reshape)) # <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
print(type(np.reshape)) # <class 'function'>
```

Are there practical differences between these approaches, or is it just about having more concise syntax?

Comment: The `method` version is "more direct" if the object is already an array.  The function version has an added layer, that allows you to use it on a list (or other object that can be converted to an array).  `np.reshape([1,2,3]. (3,1))`.  Otherwise it usually doesn't matter which you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that array reshape doesn't accept keyword arguments, it's just that the name of the argument is different. If you look at documentation for numpy.reshape (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) you'll see the keyword argument newshape, while if you look at the same for an ndarray (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) you will find that it's called shape.
Why the Numpy developers chose to call it differently is beyond me.

I think that the easiest way to learn the differences (and this is totally a personal preference) is to use Ipython and type

```
x.reshape?
```

or

```
import numpy as np
np.reshape?
```

This will basically show the same documentation I linked to, but allows you to see it while testing your code.